# Remove key from a two dimensional array (recordset)

Tags: php, arrays

I have this record set with this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => c
        )

)
```

I want to remove a property in the whole record (for example, if removing 'a' key):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [b] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [b] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [b] => c
        )

)
```

I've tried with foreach and array_map. Is there a better approach?

Comment: You tried with foreach & array_map, does that means it works with those or you're not able to get it working?

Comment: @DarkKnight both works. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_map()` and `array_filter(..., ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)` for this. The result will be a *copy* of the original array with specified key/s removed from second level items:

```
$array = [
    ["a" => 11, "b" => 12],
    ["a" => 21, "b" => 22],
    ["a" => 31, "b" => 32]
];

$keys_to_remove = ["a"];
$result = array_map(function ($item) use ($keys_to_remove) {
    return array_filter($item, function ($key) use ($keys_to_remove) {
        return in_array($key, $keys_to_remove) === false;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

for 2-dimensional forach is a good approach. for multi-dimensional use recursive function

```
function removekey($array, $key){
  if(is_array($array)){
    if($array[$key]) unset($array[$key]);
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
      if(is_array($v)){
        $array[$k] = removekey($v, $key);
      }
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
```

example:

```
$arr = [
"0" => ["a" => "foo", "b" => "bar"],
"1" => ["3" => ["a" => "bar"], "4" => "ddd"],
"a" => ["a" => [],],
"3" => ["b" => ["c" => "foo", "b" => ["a" => "foo", "b" => "bar"]]]
];
print_r(removekey($arr, "a"));
```